# How to create a consistent navbar using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, electron

I have my navbar inside `index.html` file and I am loading it inside my `homePage.html` file as follow:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script>
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require("jquery")
</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="navbar">

    </div>

    <div id="page-wrapper">

    </div>
</body>


    <script>
        $(function(){
            $("#navbar").load("./navbar/index.html");
        });
    </script>
</html>
```

when I put random data inside `page-wrapper` they become overshadowed by the navbar.

I have worked with `Meteor` before and there we have something called `{{yield}}` that we use to indicate that the rest of the content should go here.

How is it accomplished in jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="page-wrapper">
```

could be changed to

```
<div id="page-wrapper" style="margin-top:10%">
```

I believe change the css should fix your problem.